# How to resolve MVC4 Twitter Bootstrap project fail from simple Nuget installations in VS2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I'm having an issue with launching a MVC4 application with the Twitter bootstrap.

In VS 2012, I created a new empty MVC4 application, installed the following packages:

- Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4
- Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.sample

Seems like some navigation route options-related issues, as I am going through these few turorials [Link 1](http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2012/12/31/using-mvc-navigation-routes-in-twitter-bootstrap-mvc4/) and [Link 2](http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2012/11/20/twitter-bootstrap-mvc4-the-template-nuget-package-for-asp-net-mvc4-projects/).

In reading the note about possible compile issues, I restarted the solution, but errors I'm receiving aren't the ones in the readme and are focused around the `NavigationRouteOptions`, `NavigationRouteFilters`, `RouteValueDictionary`, `FilterToken` and `HasFilterToken`:

```
'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'HasFilterToken' and no extension method 'HasFilterToken' accepting a 
first argument of type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   
...\AdministrationRouteFilter.cs    18  

'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'FilterToken' and no extension method 'FilterToken' accepting a 
first argument of type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   
..\AdministrationRouteFilter.cs 20  

The name 'NavigationRouteFilters' does not exist in the current context 

'NavigationRouteOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have confirmed that I do have `navigationroutes.mvc4` Nuget package installed as well.

Is this only working in VS 2013?

The Nuget packages are dated October 26, 2013.

Assistance appreciated.

Comment: It's November 19th and I'm having the same issue with the nuget installation package on VS2012.  When I applied the fix provided by Muthu I had a runtime error due to duplicate calls in Application_Start() to RegisterRoutes().  I'm surprised this issue hasn't been resolved yet...

Comment: So there's always a danger in applying Nuget packages to projects - you don't always know what they're adding as dependencies, and simply adding them doesn't give you a good idea about how they're wired in.  Bootstrap is simply a UI template.  I applied my own template and am wiring it in myself... no short-cuts.

Comment: sequence for install/uninstall will work as below
PM> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4 -version 1.0.90

PM> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.htmlhelpers -version 1.0.90

PM> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.sample -Version 1.0.90

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It seems there is already a discussion about the error in [github](https://github.com/erichexter/twitter.bootstrap.mvc/issues/99#)

try uninstalling 1.1.100 and install 1.0.90 versions in the following order.

> - PM> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.sample -Version 1.0.90
> - PM> Uninstall-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.htmlhelpers -Force
> - PM> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.htmlhelpers -version 1.0.90
> - PM> Uninstall-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4 -Force
> - PM> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4 -version 1.0.90

Comment: Thanks.  That got me further along, however, in duplicate entries in Global.asax.cs for `*.RegisterBundles` and `*.RegisterRoutes` exist which will cause duplicate route-related exceptions.  Removing those renders the UI but no CSS and `/bundles/modernizr` not found...

Comment: Shared layout files contain invalid CSS routes; replaced these but also noticed references to `~/Content/css-responsive` - which does not exist.  Is there a stable installation procedure documented somewhere?

Comment: Viewing in Chrome.  But that doesn't explain why the paths are actually missing/incorrect in the code.

Comment: AFAIK 1.0.90 is a stable one. not sure y u got probs

Comment: Is there a fully-working sample solution that is downloadable from somewhere?

Comment: Apparently creating the project in VS2013 has no issues... vs2012 still issues.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 this works for me, though I had to edit Global.asax.cs in order to remove some duplicated lines.

Comment: i got same issue i cant solve it, please let me know how to solve it

Comment: hi @Muthu, how do you solve this issue i have getting above problem could you please explain how to solve it.

Comment: This helped quite a bit. I also had to force uninstall the navigationroutes.mvc4 package and then re-install it to actually get the navroutes files. I also had to blow away the duplicate RegisterRoutes, RegisterBundle calls in Global.asax.cs. I'm using VS2013

Answer (score 5):

Good morning fellas, i have run into the exact same issue, and at least for me, this worked>

instead of installing twetter.bootstrap, just install the bootstrap package, because it looks like with the release of vs2013, they just handed the package over, to MS maintenance.

so, uninstall your current bootstrap version, (the twitter one) and just install general bootstrap. (or be sure to be installing version 3.0.2)

```
install-package bootstrap
```

note that this fix, applies to VS2k12.

Comment: Yep, I was having all of the same problems as the OP and others, so I uninstalled everything and ran "install-package bootstrap" as you suggested and everything worked out of the box so to speak.  Thanks!!

Comment: The same is true for me as well. Thanks @Pablo Contreras

Answer (score 1):

For me this tutorial about how to setup ASP.NET MVC 4 and Twitter Bootstrap works fine: https://www.macaw.nl/weblog/2013/5/setting-up-a-solution-with-mvc4-and-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Muthu's solution works if you create an VS2012 project (Basic --- NOT the Internet!), then add the css files in the bootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml (which you will find in the shared folder) and add the Javascript files at the bottom of bootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml. Here is my bootstraplayout.basic.cshtml. Note... the order of the script files is important (Good luck!) ... and THANKS Mithu!

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
@using BootstrapSupport
@using NavigationRoutes
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        @*<link href="@Styles.Url("~/content/css")" rel="stylesheet"/>*@
 @*   @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")*@
        <link href="~/Content/body.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        @RenderSection("head", required: false)
        @Html.Partial("_html5shiv")
        @* favicons and touch icons go here *@
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="brand" href="#" title="change in _bootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml">Application Name</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            @Html.Navigation()
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="container">
            @Html.Partial("_alerts")
            @Html.Partial("_validationSummary")
            @RenderBody()   
            <hr>
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; Company @System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")</p>
            </footer> 
        </div>
         @*@Scripts.Render("~/js")*@
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive-custom-for-bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

         @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```