# Edit bootstrap in Mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

Installing bootstrap in mvc4 then examplelayoutrouteconfig.cs class contains error

```
public class ExampleLayoutsRouteConfig
   {
       public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
       {
           routes.MapNavigationRoute<HomeController>("Automatic Scaffolding", c => c.Index());

           routes.MapNavigationRoute<ExampleLayoutsController>("Example Layouts", c => c.Starter())
                 .AddChildRoute<ExampleLayoutsController>("Marketing", c => c.Marketing())
                 .AddChildRoute<ExampleLayoutsController>("Fluid", c => c.Fluid())
                 .AddChildRoute<ExampleLayoutsController>("Sign In", c => c.SignIn())
               ;
       }
   }
```

Comment: What is the error? Does uninstalling bootstrap fix it?

Comment: for making view i want use bootstrap i have tried to reinstall it but no luck.

Comment: I just installed Twitter Bootstrap for ASP.Net MVC 4 Sample 1.1.100, it gave the following error:
Error 1 The name 'NavigationRouteFilters' does not exist in the current context
Error 2 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'HasFilterToken' and no extension method 'HasFilterToken' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Error 3 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'FilterToken' and no extension method 'FilterToken' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error 4 The type or namespace name 'NavigationRouteOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

try uninstall latest version of navigationroutes.mvc4 and install 1.0.90

> - PM> Uninstall-Package navigationroutes.mvc4 -Force
> - PM> Install-Package navigationroutes.mvc4 -version 1.0.90

P.S. I assume you have moved other packages to 1.0.90 as well
[How to resolve MVC4 Twitter Bootstrap project fail from simple Nuget installations in VS2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618771/how-to-resolve-mvc4-twitter-bootstrap-project-fail-from-simple-nuget-installatio/19638918#19638918)