# Installing twitter bootsrap package in MVC 4 jquery version not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

I installed

**PM> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.sample**

This was the error result. I don't know how to downgrade my jquery; I use empty template.

`Install-Package : Updating 'jQuery 1.9.1' to 'jQuery 1.4.1' failed. Unable to find versions of 'Twitter.Bootstrap, jQuery.Migrate, Microsof
t.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax, Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation' that are compatible with 'jQuery 1.4.1'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.sample
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand`

Answer (score 1):

I see that I arrived at the party a little bit late, but I ran into the same problem so I thought I'd go ahead and answer it for anyone else encountering this issue.

First create an **ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application**, then select the **Empty** Project Template.

Open the NuGet Package Manage Console and enter these commands:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
PM> Install-Package jQuery.Validation
PM> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4 -version 1.0.90
```

Then if you want to install the Mvc4 sample project as well you need to enter these commands:

```
PM> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.sample -Version 1.0.90
PM> Uninstall-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.htmlhelpers -Force
PM> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.htmlhelpers -version 1.0.90    
PM> Uninstall-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4 -Force
PM> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4 -version 1.0.90
```

You have to force install version 1.0.90, because the sample project will not compile correctly. Source: [How to Resolve Bootsrap Project Fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618771/how-to-resolve-mvc4-twitter-bootstrap-project-fail-from-simple-nuget-installatio)

After doing all this to get the project working I ran it and the Navigation stuff was broken... so I proceeded to delete it all.

I know I may have answered a bit more than what the question was asking for, but I hope this helped!